# Convert hexadecimal value to ascii

Tags: java, ascii, hex

I have a java code that reads a memory file and display the hexadecimal value of the content. I want to convert that output to ASCII. Since i am new to java programming i need your valuable help. Please help me to do this. If you have any idea or any programs please send it to me. Thank you.

```
final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.dmp");

   final byte[] buf = new byte[512];
   int readSize = 0;
   while ((readSize = fis.read(buf)) > -1) {
for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
    final byte curByte = buf[i];
    System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", curByte));
}   
}fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the hex string in groups of two and use the function `Integer.parseInt(subString, 16);` to convert it to an integer. You can then cast it to a `byte` or `char`.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 Integer.toString((int)b, 10);
```

this how Byte class in java does